# Why do you need to specify @Configuration when you want to use @PropertySource in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I know you use @Configuration when you want to add @Bean for ApplicationContext.
But why do you need to specify @Configuration when you want to use @PropertySource in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

From the API documentaion of [`@PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html):

> Annotation providing a convenient and declarative mechanism for adding
> a [`PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html) to Spring's Environment. To be used in conjunction
> with [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) classes.

So, it can be deduced that Spring will register a [`org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html) bean if we use `@PropertySource` which will be managed by the Spring container. And `@Configuation` is needed for declaring Spring beans.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you!